# Prebuilding different kind of static library in Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, static-libraries

Is there any way that we can build different kind of static libraries (.a extension files) at once, that we created through our NDK ? I think you'll understand better when i shared the code.

Android.mk ->

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libzlib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libzlib.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libpng
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libpng.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := callNDK
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := callNDK.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libpng libzlib

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The static libraries that I include, I copied from the /obj folder that I created with the `BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY`. How can I prebuilt them all at once and include them ? Sorry for the bad English and thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer with the variable, `TARGET_ARCH_ABI`. Adding `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ..\obj\local\$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)\libzlib.a` line on each prebuilt library fixed the problem. Basiclly, it chooses the appropriate library on each compile & install.